# bash, regex, post process row and column data

Tags: regex, bash, logging, awk, sed

My project is to extract specific data from log files.

The data has columns and rows; some are text strings, some are numeric.

To extract only the rows of information I am interested in I tried an awk command that used to work (ages ago) that looked like this:

```
awk '{if($1 == text1Exp || textExp2 || textExp3) {print $1, $2}}' file.log
```

Well, that didn't work so well.  Searching gave me the following syntax which worked well:

```
awk '/Counter/ || /IfInErrors/ || /IfOutErrors/ {print $0}'
```

I made a short script that worked well:

```
for i in `ls`; do awk '/Counter/ || /IfInErrors/ || /IfOutErrors/ {print $0}' $i > $i.csv; done
```

I processed over 200 files with just the data I wanted.  Now I needed the data to be importable as a csv file with tabs and spaces all set to one length.  I accomplished this iteratively using the following:

```
sed -i 's/  */ /g' *.csv   # all tab white space and white space set
```

Followed by:

```
sed -i "s/ /,/g" *.csv     # substitute spaces with a comma.
```

There were a few other substitutions that cleaned up the format of the data.  Now I have the data looking clean like this:

```
,Counter Name,port 1/1/x33,port 1/1/x34,port 1/1/x35,port 1/1/x36
,IfInErrors:,0,0,0,0
,IfOutErrors:,0,0,0,0
,Counter Name,port 1/1/x37,port 1/1/x38,port 1/1/x39,port 1/1/x40
,IfInErrors:,**95**,0,0,0
,IfOutErrors:,0,0,0,0
```

(I know about the leading comma but got lazy; I'll fix it in ver. 0.2a).

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Count the number of ZERO values for IfInErrors && IfOutErrors
2. Count the number of NON ZERO values for IfInErrors && IfOutErrors
3. Ignore the line with Counter ...
4. Report the sum of NON ZERO values for IfInErrors && IfOutErrors and capture in a file
5. Report the sum of zero values and capture the sum in the same file created in requirement 4.

Unfortunately Grasshopper, this exceeds your script-fu, The Master says.  :(

I tried manipulating the data in Exell but, well, you know ...

I've tried some online classes but, while they help, I'm find I learn best by doing, struggling, and working with a mentor.  I've tried to find the blind Sholin Monk that helped David Caradin but he's retired and hit me with a stick ...

Any tips?

Comment: The problem, obviously, is you mis-spelled Shaolin ;-). Edit your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output and you'll probably get some help.

Answer (score 3):

So, the first and second attempts do need some work -- as the if/then does not work the way you are thinking... Also, the delimiter substitution can be handled very easily with **awk** using the **OFS** built-in variable.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="," } $1 ~ /^Counter/ || $1 ~ /^IfInErrors/ || $1 ~ /^IfOutErrors/ { $1=$1; print > FILENAME ".csv" }' file.log
```

This code checks the first field with a more restrictive regular expression that includes the idea of "starts with" or "^".  Notice that in each case, we must repeat "$1 ~" each time.... this is also needed if we were to put this into the original "if statement".  But... we can ALSO construct a more succinct regular expression that will handle all your cases at once without the logical or's...

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="," } $1 ~ /^Counter|^If(In|Out)Errors/ { $1=$1; print > FILENAME ".csv" }' file.log
```

The `OFS=","` statement sets the output delimiter to comma. And the `$1=$1` actually applies the change of delimiter to the input line.  An unqualified print statement prints the current line buffer. The `> FILENAME ".csv"` outputs to the file you want.

This gets us to the following:

```
Counter,Name,port,1/1/x33,port,1/1/x34,port,1/1/x35,port,1/1/x36
IfInErrors:,0,0,0,0
IfOutErrors:,0,0,0,0
Counter,Name,port,1/1/x37,port,1/1/x38,port,1/1/x39,port,1/1/x40
IfInErrors:,**95**,0,0,0
IfOutErrors:,0,0,0,0
```

This is different from your output, but it is what I would expect from your script -- because all white-space here is converted to single comma. I *think* you actually had a tab delimited file to begin with; so, if you find you really don't want all the commas in the above we can specify the input delimiter the BEGIN section:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS="," } $1 ~ /^Counter|^If(In|Out)Errors/ { $1=$1; print > FILENAME ".csv" }' file.log
```

Which results in something more like what you have in your example output:

```
Counter Name,port 1/1/x33,port 1/1/x34,port 1/1/x35,port 1/1/x36
IfInErrors:,0,0,0,0
IfOutErrors:,0,0,0,0
Counter Name,port 1/1/x37,port 1/1/x38,port 1/1/x39,port 1/1/x40
IfInErrors:,**95**,0,0,0
IfOutErrors:,0,0,0,0
```

If you don't have simple tab delimiting and want more stripping of delimiters, a more complex regular expression can be used for `FS`.

For the rest of what you need, it would be helpful to clarify by... showing us an example of the output especially because part your question currently asks for the value of the sum of 0...  which is...  Um...  0.  A helpful hint would be to use a for loop with a couple counters.... something like the following clause:

```
$1 ~ /^If(In|Out)Errors/ {
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
                gsub(/\*/, "", $i)
                if ($i == 0) {
                        z++
                } else {
                        nz++
                        s += $i
                }
        }
}
```

And do something in an END { } clause and change of FILENAME like:

```
END || filename != FILENAME {
        if (z || nz || s) {
                print filename ": " z, nz, s
                z=nz=s=0
        }
        filename=FILENAME
}
```

Comment: Wow, so much cleaner than mine!  Thank you Michael.